# What is "Windows Server Networking Helper Service" and why is it spamming UDP broadcasts?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

On our Windows Small Business Server 2008 machine, this service is constantly sending large numbers of 13 byte UDP datagrams to 255.255.255.255. These datagrams contain the bytes 0x7805, followed by the hostname of the server.

What is this service, and how is it actually "helping" our network? How do we stop the packet spam without breaking anything else? Have we misconfigured this machine, and if so, how do we fix it?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you consider to be "large numbers"? Is this actually causing performance issues?

Comment: About 700 datagrams per second. Just transmitting these is using over 1% of the CPU constantly, and this is the fastest machine on our network. Receiving all those interrupts is hammering our lower specced hardware.